# Powershell error The string is missing the terminator: '

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I have the below scripts & run on the Windows 2012 R2 server. This scripts will create AppPool & site in IIS.

```
Import-Module "WebAdministration"

if(Test-Path IIS:\AppPools\MgmtSite){ } else { New-Item IIS:\AppPools\MgmtSite -force  }

if(Test-Path 'iis:\Sites\Mgmt Site'){ New-WebBinding -name 'Mgmt Site' -Protocol http -IPAddress '*' -Port 80 } else { New-Item 'iis:\Sites\Mgmt Site' -bindings @{protocol='http';bindingInformation='*:80:'} -physicalPath 'C:\Program Files\AP\MgmtServices' -force }

Set-ItemProperty 'iis:\Sites\Mgmt Site' -name applicationPool -value MgmtSite

$newId = (Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites | where{$_.Name -eq 'Mgmt Site'}).Id

Write-Host -Object "Mgmt Site ID is: $newId " 

New-WebBinding -name 'Mgmt Site' -Protocol https -IPAddress '*' -Port 443 -SslFlags 0

Start-WebSite 'Mgmt Site' 

 if( !((Get-WebConfiguration //staticcontent).collection | ? {$_.fileextension -eq '.woff'}) ) {  add-webconfigurationproperty //staticContent -name collection -value @{fileExtension='.woff'; mimeType='application/font-woff'}   } 

 if( !((Get-WebConfiguration //staticcontent).collection | ? {$_.fileextension -eq '.woff2'}) ) {  add-webconfigurationproperty //staticContent -name collection -value @{fileExtension='.woff2'; mimeType='application/font-woff2'}   } 

 if( !((Get-WebConfiguration //staticcontent).collection | ? {$_.fileextension -eq '.webm'}) ) {  add-webconfigurationproperty //staticContent -name collection -value @{fileExtension='.webm'; mimeType='video/webm'}   }
```

While executing on the server getting the below error,

```
> At C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\2\nsz8E60.tmp\temp_script.ps1:11 char:213
+ ... ype='video/webm'}   }
+                    ~~~~~~
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

But the same script is working on other servers. [Poweshell version is 4.0 on the server]
Could any one help on this.

Comment: What specific PowerShell version and how is the script being invoked (it looks like it's auto-generated)? As posted, the script by itself does not explain your symptom.

Comment: the server has PS 4.0 version and the script is invoked via Installer, this script is dynamically created during package installation & executing

Comment: [1] check for invalid chars [for instance, an `em-dash` instead of `hyphen`]. [2] load your code into VSCode and run the `format document` command. that will let you see your code in a better layout ... and may make your glitch easier to find.

Comment: If you can manually run the script on the server, try commenting out a line at a time, starting from the end of the script until the error disappears. That'll help narrow down the exact line where the error is and might give a clue to what's causing it...

Comment: there was a typo error while dynamically updating the IP address value in the script when executing the installer.exe with pre-configured value. Thanks for pointing @mclayton